# A query to know if sybase procedure is hidden or not

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have procedure that is hidden , I know it hard to unhide the procedure on sybase but is there a query that tells the procedure if its hidden or not ? I tried sysobjects but it I couldnt find any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indicated by the syscomments.status columns.
See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1600/doc/html/san1393052468258.html